# how to search "moment to <word> <word> move" in elasticsearch by kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i'm using kibana-4.5.0, elasticsearch 2.3.2

i have those sentences. "The moment to save and move etc...", "The moment to kill and move ...." in elasticsearch

so i want to search "moment to   move"

how can i do in kibana or rest-api?

i tried this span near query,,, i don't know what "slop" means? i think that slop is the word count.. but i coundn't search those sentences...

```
{
  "query": {
    "span_near": {
      "clauses": [
        {
          "span_term": {
            "items": "to"
          }
        },
        {
          "span_term": {
            "items": "move"
          }
        }
      ],
      "in_order": true,
      "slop": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe filtering by regular expression will do the trick?

```
{
  "filter": {
    "regexp": {
      "items": "moment to [a-z]+ [a-z]+ move"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i do this example?

Comment: Same way you was executing you code from original question